# Call MVC post method from postman and send parameters to it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postman

I need to test this mvc method from postman, it is working in Browser.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("login")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LogInRequest logInRequest)
    {
        User user = null;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {            
            .....
```

This is LogInRequest Class:

```
   public class LogInRequest
  {  
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }  
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public bool IsResetPassword { get; set; }
    public bool IsThankYouPage { get; set; }
     }
```

I am not sure how to sent the LogInRequest parameter using Postman. anything I try it is not hitting the breakpoints in first line of this method.

This  is how I call the local URL and send parameter to this method.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you be posting to `/Login`?

Comment: @stephen.vakil oh yes thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old question but it may be helping the others.
You should use the Route which you provided in the controller e.g

```
[Route("login")]
```

Url in postman call should be like this

```
HTTP:/localhost:12xx3/login.
```